# Module field with feeds, module generating data

Tags: drupal, field

I have an issue with triming a field before it is saved. I wanted to use `substr()`, or `regex()` with `preg_match()`. I have built a Drupal 7 module, but it can't work at all. I have tried using the trim plugin in feeds tamper module, but it doesn't seem to work. The data I am using is from a feed from Google Alerts. I have posted this issue [here](http://drupal.org/node/1595384).

This is what I have done so far, and I know my regular expression is wrong; I was trying to get it do anything, just to see if I could get it to work, but I am pretty lost on how to add this type of function to a Drupal module.

```
function sub_node_save() {    
   $url = $node->field_web_screenhot['und'][0]['url'];
   $url = preg_match('~^(http|ftp)(s)?\:\/\/((([a-z0-9\-]*)(\.))+[a-z0-9]*)($|/.*$)~i',$url );
   $node->field_web_screenhot['und'][0]['url'] =$url;

  return ;
}
```

I used the Devel module to get the field.

If there's an easy way to use `substr()`, I would consider that or something else.

Basically, I just want to take the Google redirect off the URL, so it is just the basic URL to the web site.

Comment: - No arguments in the function ?
- Send $node object as a reference (&$node). 
- Also, could you explain what you need to be saved after the preg_match with some example ?

Comment: Hi, Okay I would not have known there was not any argument still starting out. I have a rss feed from google alerts that generates a url for a website that goes into a link module field. I wanted preg_match to identify the basic url in the middle without the google redirect info in the front and string in the back I wanted to strip out the stuff I don't need.

Comment: A google alert url looks like this http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=http%3A//www.rollingstone.com/music/news/chili-peppers-neil-young-jack-white-black-keys-to-headline-austin-city-limits-fest-2012-20120522&ct=ga&cad=CAcQARgBIAAoATAAOABA7tHs_QRIAlAAWABiBWVuLVVT&cd=Ssi-dxG-suk&usg=AFQjCNGGqfR87j6MisLOPHiK01tmERP19w   I want to grab the url in the middle on node save

http%3A//www.rollingstone.com/music/news/chili-peppers-neil-young-jack-white-black-keys-to-headline-austin-city-limits-fest-2012-20120522   thanks very much for your help!!!!!

Comment: Does that make sense I can provide more info to help answer the question thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your question and later comments, I'd suggesting using node_presave hook (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) for this. 
It's called before both insert (new) and update ops so you will need extra validations to prevent it from executing on node updates if you want.

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
// check if nodetype is "mytype"
    if ($node->type == 'mytype'){
        // PHP's parse_url to get params set to an array.
        $parts = parse_url($node->field_web_screenhot['und'][0]['url']); 
        // Now we explode the params by "&" to get the URL.
        $queryParts = explode('&', $parts['query']);

        $params = array();
        foreach ($queryParts as $param) {
            $item = explode('=', $param);
            $params[$item[0]] = $item[1];
        } 
        //valid_url validates the URL (duh!), urldecode() makes the URL an actual one with fixing "//" in http, q is from the URL you provided.
        if (valid_url(urldecode($parms['q']))){
            $node->field_web_screenhot['und'][0]['url'] = urldecode($parms['q']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright I am going to try this. I see where your going with this. I was think presave also too. I will report back if I am able to get this to work. thanks again for your help!

Comment: May be a regex will do the job quickly/effectively/less-memory but I simply don't know much about regex.

Google and you will find a LOT of regex patterns to get specific params from a URL.

Comment: Does the code you provided do any triming of the url or does that needed to be added still ?

Comment: trim(urldecode($parms['q']))
Won't make a difference but if you want, use above ti replace urldecode($parms['q'])

Comment: When I added that code to the module I am getting several errors now http://c626951.r51.cf2.rackcdn.com/statusreport.png please take a look at these I really appreciate it thanks!!!!

Comment: I might be not explaining completely right - I want to remove the parts of the url that I dont want and return the parts that I do want to field so I am able to get a googleless url. Does that make sense? thanks again for all your help I found this page but I am having a bit of trouble understanding it  http://snipplr.com/view/6526/split-an-url-into-protocol-site-and-resource-parts/